# Convert string with wrong encoding to utf8

Tags: python

I have this string `Î¤ÎµÏƒÏ„ - Test` with wrong encoding.

It was this text: `Τεστ - Test` and it was re-opened with `Western Windows-1252` and saved with `utf-8` encoding.
So now whenever I open this files in my editor (Sublime) I need to re-open with encoding `utf-8` to read the values.

I need to convert the texts using python.
I am trying this:

```
import codecs

my_text = 'Î¤ÎµÏƒÏ„ - Test'
try1 = bytes(my_text, 'utf-8')
try2 = codecs.escape_decode(my_text)[0]
try3 = str(my_text.encode('unicode_escape').decode('windows-1252'))
//try1 :  b'\xc3\x8e\xc2\xa4\xc3\x8e\xc2\xb5\xc3\x8f\xc6\x92\xc3\x8f\xe2\x80\x9e - Test'
//try2 :  b'\xc3\x8e\xc2\xa4\xc3\x8e\xc2\xb5\xc3\x8f\xc6\x92\xc3\x8f\xe2\x80\x9e - Test'
//try3 : \xce\xa4\xce\xb5\xcf\u0192\xcf\u201e - Test
```

I am trying to convert this encoded string in order to get the proper value using decode('utf-8').

```
try1 = try1.decode('utf-8')
try2 = try2.decode('utf-8')
```

But I get `Î¤ÎµÏƒÏ„ - Test` again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works for me (in Python 3):

```
s = "Î¤ÎµÏƒÏ„ - Test"
assert s.encode("cp1252").decode("utf-8") == "Τεστ - Test"
```

So the first call to encode encodes it to the string of bytes using `cp1252`, and then that list of bytes is decoded using `utf-8` resulting in the expected unicode string.

Answer (score 2):

Your text was at the beginning in utf-8, then opened as bytes and decoded as if it was cp1252, then re-encoded as utf-8, so basically if we wrote it in python it would be:

```
>>> "Τεστ - Test".encode('utf-8').decode('cp1252')
'Î¤ÎµÏƒÏ„ - Test'
```

So the inverse operation is:

```
>>> 'Î¤ÎµÏƒÏ„ - Test'.encode('cp1252').decode('utf-8')
'Τεστ - Test'
```